# Unescaped model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, brakeman

I have installed brakeman and getting security vulnerabilities.

Here is my warning

**Unescaped model attribute rendered inline near line 24: render(inline => SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], WeeklyNewsletterFactory.new.email(:preview => true)).html_part.body.raw_source, {})**

**Line:24**

```
render inline: SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source
```

I have tried this solution as suggested by brakeman but after doing this I start getting error Could not parse

```
render(inline: SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source,{})
```

Rails - 4.2.4
Brakeman - 3.1.2
Ruby -  2.3.1

Comment: why I am getting this warning Unescaped model attribute rendered inline. And how to resolve it. Brakeman says it is cross-site scripting vulnerability

Comment: What is line 24?

Comment: I have already inserted code for line 24                                                     render inline: SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673359/brakeman-error-unescaped-model-attribute-near

Comment: That's not a similar question. Please go through it once again

Comment: What solution have you tried? Where did you find it? What exact error do you get?

Comment: I have already posted the solution which I have tried just below my question. I find it in brakeman suggestions. I have updated my question so you can see the exact error now

Comment: What does `SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source` return? A HTML fragment? A full HTML page? Just the text from the HTML Mail? Did you escape the everything within the Mailer view (aka is the returned value HTML safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **Premailer::Rails::Hook.perform**

```
Premailer::Rails::Hook.perform(SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email)).html_part.body.raw_source
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `render inline: ...`, Rails will treat the text passed in as an ERB template. This means if the string you provide has any `<%...%>` tags in it (or the possibility of an attacker inserting them), they will be executed as Ruby code.

If that is what you want, then there is no problem. [Ignore the warning.](https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/ignoring_false_positives/) But keep in mind this is dangerous! **If an attacker can manipulate the text to insert ERB tags, they can execute arbitrary code on your server.**

If you just want to output some HTML, use

```
render html: SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source.html_safe
```

(Note there is the possibility of [cross-site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) if you are not escaping user input inside of the email).

If you meant to output plaintext, use

```
render plain: SendGridMailer.weekly_email([current_user], email).html_part.body.raw_source
```

Also, Brakeman does not output suggested code fixes, so you are likely misinterpreting the report.

Answer (score 1):

in a view you can add `h()` to escape the value and remove the brakeman warning